# How to set TensorFlow 2.0 as the default version in Google Collab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Within Google Collab, every time I load it up after restarting my computer, I have to run the following commands to uninstall the default, 1.15.0 version of TensorFlow and instead install 2.0.

How can 2.0 be set as the default so I don't have to keep doing this please?

This is the code that I currently have to load every time:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: What specific features of tensorflow 2.0 are you trying to use in CoLab? Depending on what those are, there might be a way to do that without installing 2.0.0.

Comment: Hey @ShanqingCai! Without 2.0 I get this error: RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.

Comment: OK. Sounds like you just need the eager execution feature. Can you just try running these lines in the beginning? `tf.enable_v2_behavior()`.

Comment: Ah nice one! That has done it, thanks! Not a true solution, I still get an error warning that I should upgrade, but it's fixed the issue so I definitely can't complain! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit, April 2020:* tensorflow 2.x is now the default in Colab

---

*Original answer:*

See https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb

At the top of your notebook run

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```

This will enable tensorflow 2.0 without needing to download and install it.